# What type of function is this (pointer function with code)?

Tags: c, function, types

This is the first time I am seeing something like this where a function is like a pointer (but it is not a function pointer ??). See example below.

```
static struct test *MyFunc(struct astr *A, int count)
{

}

MyFunc(B, 100);
```

Can someone explain how the above works as well as why you would use a pointer function (if that is the correct term) as well as why not simply use

```
 static struct test MyFunc(struct astr *A, int count)
```

Comment: It's just a function that returns a pointer. There's nothing special about that, pointers are values just like anything else.

Comment: Move the \* next to the _type_ it applies to. Same as: int \*x().. vs int\* x().. in this case the type is struct test. That should help clarify/eliminate a substantial part of the question as there is no “function like pointer” involved.

Comment: It's a function returning a pointer of type `struct test *`. It can potentially allocate one (with `malloc()` or similar) and return it. Or just return one from a lookup in a hash or tree or list etc. (i.e. something that wouldn't require the caller to free it.) Returning `struct test` typically requires that there's a copy at the end of the function, copying the struct fields at the time of assignment. It can be inefficient and expensive.

Comment: It can also return a pointer to a `static` local `struct`, which is safe but not thread-safe.

Comment: The answer to "why" in `why not simply use` depends on the context. How is the return value obtained from this function used?

Comment: Aaaaah of course ! struct test * is what it returns and MyFunc is the name of the function ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's look at the function declaration:

```
static struct test *MyFunc(struct astr *A, int count)
```

The function itself is **static** (Local to the file it was declared in), and returns a **pointer** (Location in memory) to a value with a `struct test` type. In other words, it is a **static** function with return type `struct test *`.

Remember: Static function declarations specify the storage class of the **function itself**, not the **return type**.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way:

```
static (struct test *) MyFunc(struct astr *A, int count)
```